# How to get original data when update Model Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel

I have orders table I need to get the `Original` value of order in order the admin change it:

I used `getOriginal` and `getAttributes()['column_name']` and always store the same value of status :(

```
  $order->update([
        'status' => $request->status
    ]);

    $order->orders_status_reports()->attach($order->id,[
        'old_status' => $order->getOriginal('status'),
        'new_status' => $order->status,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can attach old status before updating order :

```
$new_status = $request->status;

$order->orders_status_reports()->attach($order->id,[
            'old_status' => $order->status,
            'new_status' => $new_status,
        ]);

$order->update(['status' => $new_status]);
```

Comment: Thank you abo humed ;)